# If I flagged a comment as 'Rude or Offensive', and it was marked 'helpful', why is it still there?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, flagging

The title basically says it all - If I flagged a comment as 'Rude or Offensive', and it was marked 'helpful', why is it still there?

The comment contained... eerr... explicit *reproductive* content. (I'm not saying what comment, or who posted it.) I flagged it as Offensive. The flag was marked helpful. But *the comment is still there*. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment you flagged was deleted by the user who posted it, marking your flag helpful. (Comment flags are dismissed as helpful when the comment is deleted, regardless of who deleted it.)

They subsequently re-posted only a few seconds after deleting it, but with a minor one-word change.